# Struts 2.3.16.3 upgrade - modal dialog (popup) not opening

Tags: struts2, struts2-jquery

I upgraded struts from 2.3.15.3 to 2.3.16.3.

struts jquery plugin - 3.7.1

struts jquery tree plugin - 3.7.1

java servlet api - 2.4

jquery-ui.js - 1.10.4

I have done the above changes! css are working and jquery is also working fine. But none of the modal dialogs (popups) are opening up. Have I missed Anything?
Can you help me in this?

I use tiles in my app. modallayout is not working..
This is how I open the popup

```
<s:url var="editURL"  action="edit" namespace="/app/edit"  method="load" escapeAmp="false"/>

<td onclick="openedit('<s:property value="#editURL"/>','<s:property value="Id" escape="false"/>')">
<sj:a 
id="editCPlink" 
button="true"
href="#"
>
Edit
</sj:a>
</td>

function openedit(modalURL,Id) {
var options_modaldialog = {};
winopen(options_modaldialog);
options_modaldialog.height = 250;
options_modaldialog.width = 870;
options_modaldialog.title = 'Edit';
options_modaldialog.id = "editdialog";
options_modaldialog.position = [ 250, 40 ];
options_modaldialog.href = modalURL;
jQuery.struts2_jquery.bind(jQuery('#editdialog'),
options_modaldialog);
}
```

Comment: Very strange, your versions of libraries are correctly chosen; since the code was working, I won't ask for it, but at least post the javascript console errors / warnings to get help

Comment: Show your modal dialog and how you are opening it.

Comment: I am not getting any warnings or errors. when I click on the button/link nothing is happening..

Comment: I have given my code of how to open popup.

Comment: If you use s2-jquery-plugin then use it to open dialog. If not use plain jQuery. What you have is a very *strange* code.

Comment: this is plain jquery using onclick=""

Comment: Plain jQuery using **onclick**? And this `jQuery.struts2_jquery.bind`?

Comment: do we have any issues reported in struts2-jquery plugin regarding this popup issue..

Comment: Do you have DMI enabled ?

Comment: You need to check javascript error in console. See it and if there is any error please post it here.

Comment: Do you have a version conflict?

Comment: @ Andrea Ligios - DMI is disabled

Comment: @ Parth Trivedi - I do not get any error in console. :(

Comment: @ Roman C - I think version conflict is the issue. but how do I debug with no errors in console. :(

Comment: @ Aleksandr M - I found something... when I used jQuery.struts2_jquery.bind() it wasnt working but jQuery.struts2_jquery_ui.bind() is loading the popup but the jquery is not applied to the popup contents.. what does this infer? The version conflict?

Comment: SCRIPT438: Object doesn't support property or method 'widget'
SCRIPT5007: Unable to get value of the property 'msie': object is null or undefined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally got the issue resolved.

```
jQuery.struts2_jquery.bind() have been replace by jQuery.struts2_jquery_ui.bind()
```

This is because the upgraded struts2jquery plugin 3.7.1 is more compatible with struts2_jquery_ui binding than struts2_jquery. so jQuery.struts2_jquery_ui.bind() can be used to load the popup.

Note: Make sure to replace the js and css files of all the upgraded js.